# sqlsrv_connect function returns empty string

Tags: php, sql-server, ajax

I've been working on an web app who retrieves some data from a SQL Server instance (SQL Server 2008 R2). I'm doing it trough Ajax:

```
function get_data() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'get_data.php',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
        },
        error: function(e) {
            console.log(e.responseText);
        }
    });
}
```

The "get_data.php" file:

```
<?php
    $sqlServerConection=sqlServerConnect('(local)', '1366', 'user', 'password', 'database');
    print json_encode($sqlServerConection);



    function sqlServerConnect($server, $port, $user, $password, $database) {
        $serverName = $server.'\\sqlserver,'.$port;
        $connectionInfo = array("Database"=>$database, "UID"=>$user, "PWD"=>$password);
        $conn = sqlsrv_connect($serverName, $connectionInfo);
        if( $conn === false ) {
            die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
        }

        return $conn;
    }
?>
```

The issue here is that that it always returns an error to ajax. When I check the console log the error message is always empty. If I move any parameter the sqlsrv_connect calling it returns an SQL Server access error, so I assume the function is doing it's work correctly. If I check any log on MAMP they don't show anything. Even the SQL Server log doesn't show a thing.

Any recommendation will be welcome.

Comment: Ups, you are right,  I'll change it. Thanks

Comment: Why are you trying to use instance name, `\sqlserver`, when you already have the server hostname/address and its port? Instance name resolution requires that the SQL Browser service is running on the target and is accessible via udp/1434. It's used to resolve the instance name to a TCP port number - which you already know!